# Firefox extension:adding a new tab,but addEventListener not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, addeventlistener

There is a dialog, and I define a function `OnAccept()` and call it like this: `ondialogaccept:ondialogaccept="OnAccept()"`.

```js
OnAccept():
    function OnAccept() {
        var windowManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService();
        var windowManagerInterface = windowManager.QueryInterface( Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator );
        var topWindow = windowManagerInterface.getMostRecentWindow( "navigator:browser" );
        if(topWindow)
        {
            var web = topWindow.document.getElementById("content");
            web.selectedTab = web.addTab("http://www.google.com");
            var newBrowserHandle = web.getBrowserForTab(web.selectedTab);
            newBrowserHandle.addEventListener("load", function() { alert("111"); }, true);
        }
    }
```

But the `addEventListener` doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code that are probably just bad copy&paste: `ondialogaccept:ondialogaccept="OnAccept()"` should be `ondialogaccept="OnAccept()"` and `OnAccept():` should be `OnAccept:` (without parentheses).

The main issue: the `load` event listener doesn't get propagated from content to chrome, you would need [progress listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) to get that event. You can listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event however, that one can be caught on the browser element. This event will fire when only the document content is loaded, not images and such - but maybe that's ok for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the issue is that if the dialog doesn't close,the load event listener is OK,but if the dialog closes,I can't see the alert.Does the close event of the dialog have an influence on the load listener of the new tab.